# Largest number with sum S and N number of digits

Tags: number-theory

Given a number N and sum as S .What is the mathematical approach to construct the largest number  having N digits whose sum is S and smallest number of N digits  whose sum is again S. Leading zero digit numbers are not considered.

Comment: Put the number 9 as the first digit and after the biggest one to fill the sum S, by example if S=19 and N=5 then the largest number is 99100. The smaller is the "reverse", start with 9 in the last digit and continue putting numbers and reserve a 1 to the first digit by example for the anterior case the smaller number is 10099.

Comment: Any number with $N$ digits starting with 9 is bigger than any number with $N$ digits starting with a smaller digit. Note that there are no such numbers if $S>9N$. But we get the largest by taking $[S/N]$ 9s followed by one digit $S-9[S/N]$ followed by 0s. A similar approach for the smallest, except that there is an ambiguity for the smallest: is it allowed to begin with 0s? If not start it with a 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a)Fill the first $\lfloor\frac S9 \rfloor$ digits by $9$
Fill the next digit by $S\mod9$ 
Fill the rest of the digits by $0$

(b)Fill the last $\lfloor\frac {S-1}9 \rfloor$ digits by $9$
Fill the previous digit by $S-1\mod9$ 
 Fill the rest of the digits by $0$
 Add $1$ to the first digit.

Example from the comment below, 
$S=15$, $N=2$

$\lfloor\frac {S-1}9 \rfloor = 1$

$S-1\mod9 = 5$

So, you have $59$. No remaining digits, so no $0$s. Now, the last step - add $1$ gives $69$

Comment: can u illustrate b with an example

Comment: if SUM is 15 and u have to make the smallest 2 digit number,ans is 69.By doing as per your method floor(15-1/9)=1 so i placed 9at last and for next digit i need 6 to make 69  but your method 15-1%9=5 ,so it goes wrong here.CORRECT me if my argument is wrong

Comment: You are right. My method assuming certain things.. I just exchanged two steps in my method. Now, it will take care of that wrong assumption. Thank you.

Comment: @Vin Vineeth  where is the correct version ?YOU have not yet edited it .

Comment: @satya I exchanged two steps in my method. Well, I edited it again to include your example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a number with $N$ digits in decimal base and having the digit sum $S$.

It runs down to partition the number $S$ into $N$ parts (if possible at all!), where the parts are in the range $\{ 0, \dotsc, 9 \}$ and sorting it such that either the largest parts come first for a maximal number, or such that the smallest parts come first for a minimal number. Of all feasible partitions one picks the one which comes first under the considered order.

One could pose it as [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (ILP) problem, e.g.
\begin{matrix}
\max & c^\top x \\
\text{w.r.t.} & Ax = b \\
& 0 \le x \\
& x \le 9
\end{matrix}
with
\begin{align}
c^\top &= (10^{N-1}, 10^{N-2}, \dotsc, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times N} \\
A &= (1, \dotsc, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times N} \\
x &= (x_!, \dotsc, x_N)^\top \in \mathbb{Z}^N \\
b &= (S) \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align}
and use a solver.

The minimal number is a bit trickier, because of the convention that leading $0$ digits are dropped (except for single digit numbers).